# Where 'target_id' of field_data_field... tables points?

Tags: entities, database

I'm extracting database information from a Drupal site that I have using SQL queries.
I have seen that, in the field_data_field... tables can be three type of information storage:

- **field...value:** stores the value of the field directly.
- **field...val_tid:** stores the id number of taxonomy_term_data value.
- **field...val_target_id:** stores an integer id.

I'm interested in the third field, my question is: where is this field value pointing?

Comment: `target_id` is the generic id for an entity reference field, where _I believe_ `tid` is specific to a taxonomy reference field. `target_id` should also be an id of an entity in another table.

Comment: Yes, tid is specific for taxonomies, but I need to know where `target_id` points. The values that it points should be from `node` table`, but if I link directly the data is not joined correctly

Comment: If it’s an entity reference to a taxonomy term, it joins on the taxanomy_term_data table. If it’s a reference to a node it’s the node table; for other entity types it’ll be different

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the field_data_field_{field_name} table, you will see these columns:

- entity_type: tells which type of object the target is.
- entity_id: which one in the entity table

For entityforms, you can go to the URL /admin/structure/entityform_types/manage/{entity_type}/fields, and you can see what the {field_name} refers to by finding {name} in the list.

So if you know what type of object it is, hopefully you know how to find the list of fields.

If not, go to /admin/reports/fields and search the full list for your field.